# Accessing another data context in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

Hello Stackoverflowers,

In a .xaml file, i have set a datacontext to the associated ViewModel.

```
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Contents:OverlayDesignerViewModel}">
```

Later in the file, i would like to use a class that inherit from System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.

I would like to set Interaction.Triggers in this control but I want the Command to be in the DataContext defined at the beggining of the XAML file.

```
    <Contents:DrawingCanvasCustom 
                Background="#00000000"
                Name="_drawingCanvas"
                Width="650"
                Height="450">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="CanvasMouseDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CanvasMouseDownCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CanvasOverlayView}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
```

However i have an error : "cannot rsolve property CanvasMouseDownCommand in data context of type object".

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing here `Mode=FindAncestor`

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CanvasMouseDownCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

Comment: After a few tries, i figured out that {Binding CanvasMouseDownCommand} was enough in my case. Thank you for the quick anwser.